# IntelliJ IDEA gives this error on build: class Symbol$ClassSymbol cannot be cast to class PackageElement

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-11, annotation-processing

Full error:

```
ClassCastException: class com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$ClassSymbol cannot be cast to class javax.lang.model.element.PackageElement (com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$ClassSymbol is in module jdk.compiler of loader 'app'; javax.lang.model.element.PackageElement is in module java.compiler of loader 'platform')
```

About:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-211.6693.111, built on April 6, 2021

Runtime version: 11.0.10+9-b1341.35 x86_64
VM: Dynamic Code Evolution 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 11.2.3
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 3987M
Cores: 16
Non-Bundled Plugins: name.kropp.intellij.makefile (211.6693.108), CheckStyle-IDEA (5.51.0), org.jetbrains.kotlin (211-1.4.32-release-IJ6693.72), org.jetbrains.plugins.go (211.6693.111)
Kotlin: 211-1.4.32-release-IJ6693.72
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by disabling the `Default` annotation processing in the settings:
[image: Annotation Processors]

Seems like it wasn't related to any project specific code.
After disabling it, it got enabled automatically somehow but the code at least runs!

Comment: Your image is missing, perhaps try adding it again?

Comment: @ColinAlworth, Addad. Thanks.